# how to load Different Array when table view Section Button Pressed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

I am newbie in iOS development I am developing a magazine application. In that I have used tableview which contains two section and each section has `PREVIEW` button like shown in below image. [image] I would like to show different images when `PREVIEW` button is pressed. Image array is parsed from JSON. Here all images are in array (This array contains array of images). So for first section I wrote a code like

```
NSDictionary *dict=[self.imagesa objectAtIndex:0];
```

But for second section two cell are there which uses same custom Cell. I am now confused that How to show second object array when tableview's second section `PREVIEW` button is pressed and same way load third image array when second section's second cell `Preview` button is pressed. If I make different Xibs for each button then in future if new cell is added then it will not work. Please give me solution for that here is web services link [WebService link](http://www.truemanindiamagazine.com/webservice/magazine_list.php)

I would like to show First -demopage: array for first cell and Second -demopage: for second and upto last cell of table view. How it possible please give me solution.

Here my Preview Button Code

```
UIButton *preview = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        preview.frame = CGRectMake(112,95, 89, 25);
        preview.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:229.0/256.0 green:229.0/256.0 blue:229.0/256.0 alpha:1.0f];
        [preview setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [preview setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:229.0/256.0 green:229.0/256.0 blue:229.0/256.0 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [preview setTitle:@"PREVIEW" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [preview.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"RobotoCondensed-Bold" size:14.0f]];
        [cellTwo addSubview:preview];
        [preview addTarget:self action:@selector(showPreviewSeondSection:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        preview.tag=indexPath.row;
```

And its Action like as

```
-(IBAction)showPreviewSeondSection:(id)sender
{
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
NSInteger row = button.tag;
NSLog(@"Tag of button %d",row);
}
```

But now i am Confuse how i load my demopage link array into another view Controller when my Section Row Button pressed at index.

Now i update my Question as first i parsed my -demopage key from my main array like as

```
if (responsedata.length > 0)
{
    NSError* error;

    self.json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responsedata options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    if ([[_json objectForKey:@"data"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    {
        NSArray *arr = (NSArray *)[_json objectForKey:@"data"];
        [self.imageArray addObjectsFromArray:arr];
        [self.storeViewTable reloadData];
    }
    self.storeViewTable.hidden=FALSE;
    }
    for (index=0; index<[self.imageArray count]; index++)
    {
        NSDictionary *imgDict = [self.imageArray objectAtIndex:index];
        if([imgDict count]>0)
        {
            NSMutableArray *imgsLinkArray = [imgDict objectForKey:@"demopage"];
            self.imagesa = imgsLinkArray;
        }
    }
```

and i set a tag for my Tableview Cell Button as

```
preview.tag=indexPath.row;
```

and its action like as

```
-(IBAction)showPreviewSeondSection:(id)sender
{
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
NSInteger row = button.tag;
for (index=0; index<[self.imagesa count]; index++)
{
if (row == 1)
{
    PreviewViewController *preview=[[PreviewViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PreviewViewController" bundle:nil];
    preview.imagesa=self.imagesa;
    [self presentViewController:preview animated:YES completion:nil];
    NSLog(@"Preview array %@",preview.imagesa);
}
}
}
```

then it print my -demopage array Last index in my Scrollview please give me Solution for how i press first button then i get First index value and when i press Second cell button then i want to Print second index value.

Comment: how many arrays you are using to load data in 2 sections ?

Comment: i use only one array but my array sub array that contain imagelink that i want to shown to each tableviewCell in Xib file.here my Webservice link is   http://www.truemanindiamagazine.com/webservice/magazine_list.php in this link i want to show -demopage: array value of each cell i want to show.

Answer (score 0):

while dealing with multiple sections it may help

in cellforrow  do this

```
yourcell.tag=indexpath.section;
yourcell.contentview.tag=indexpath.row;
```

and in your preview action

```
 -(void)previewbuttonAction:(id)sender
{
   UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender; // first, cast the sender to UIButton

   id rowid =[button superview];
  id sectionid = [rwoid superview];

   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[rowid tag] inSection:[sectionid tag]];

   // apply your logic here depending on the array for row and section  


}
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

In your button press method,

```
-(IBAction)showPreviewSeondSection:(id)sender
{
      CGPoint rootViewPoint = [sender.superview convertPoint:CGRectZero toView: self.storeViewTable];
      NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.storeViewTable indexPathForRowAtPoint:rootViewPoint];

     PreviewViewController *preview=[[PreviewViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PreviewViewController" bundle:nil];
     preview.imagesa=self.imagesa[indexPath.row];
     [self presentViewController:preview animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

You can get the indexPath then access the object from your array and pass into next ViewController

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64856/discussion-on-answer-by-vineesh-tp-how-to-load-different-array-when-table-view-s).